# Installing themes in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I was trying to install themes in wordpress and this error occured - Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\wordpress-3.5.2\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 953. What is this? I an not able to get it.

Comment: add `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');` to wp-config file

Answer (score 0):

Find your php.ini file, and edit the line..

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

Raise it to 60 or whatever you need. Not sure of the location of your php.ini on WAMP, but remember you can create a phpinfo file to view your php configuration to find the source of php.ini.

Comment: This is a hack around it, but depending on the operation you are performing it might be better to split the task in smaller bits and have them executed one by one with page redirection in between